# Mailchimp Ecommerce360 Javascript Implementation

Tags: javascript, rest, e-commerce, mailchimp

Wondering if anyone can provide an example of how to pass a request to the /ecomm/order-add function of the Mailchimp API using javascript. This is critical for making use of Mailchimp's Ecommerce360 tracking.

Here is documentation from Mailchimps API:
https://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/2.0/ecomm/order-add.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean from client-side Javascript, this isn't possible because the MailChimp API doesn't support [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) and (in most cases) this is a huge security issue. You'll need to communicate with Javascript back to your own servers and have those machines make the requisite API calls.